# Header skewed in pgfplot table

Tags: pgfplotstable

Can you help me fix my skewed header in this pgfplot.  For some reason, the 'k' and 'z' headers are merged.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{dataa.dat}
k      z   xbar   Pkp1   Kkp1
1 12.0000 10.0000 0.2222 0.1111
2 17.7735 15.7735 1.3846 0.6923
3 21.1068 19.1068 0.5306 0.2653
4 23.0313 21.0313 0.9703 0.4851
5 24.1424 22.1424 0.6801 0.3401
6 24.7839 22.7839 0.8474 0.4237
7 25.1543 23.1543 0.7422 0.3711
8 25.3682 23.3682 0.8050 0.4025
\end{filecontents}%


\begin{document}


%%% Code from Dr. Christian ------ for not using headers.----------------------
\pgfkeysifdefined{/pgfplots/table/output empty row/.@cmd}{
    % upcoming releases offer this more convenient option:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
          every head row/.style={output empty row},
        }
    }
}{
    % versions up to and including 1.5.1 need this:
    \pgfplotstableset{
        empty header/.style={
            typeset cell/.append code={%
                \ifnum\pgfplotstablerow=-1 %
                    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{}%
                \fi
            }
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableset{
begin table=\begin{longtable},
end table=\end{longtable},
}

\pgfplotstableset{
    % #1 = row index
    % #2 = row style keys
    row style/.style 2 args={
        every row #1 column 0/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 1/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 2/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 3/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 4/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 5/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 6/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 7/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 8/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 9/.style={#2},
        every row #1 column 10/.style={#2},
    }
}



\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=space,
empty header,
columns/k/.style={dec sep align,fixed zerofill,precision=0},
rows/z/.style={fixed zerofill,precision=5},
%columns={theta1,r2v,r3v,x,y},      % display specified columns
%columns/theta1/.style={precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$\theta_1$}},
%columns/r2v/.style={precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$r_{2v}$}},
%columns/r3v/.style={column type=1,precision=6,dec sep align,column name={$r_{3v}$}},
%columns/x/.style={column type=1,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$x$}},
%columns/y/.style={column type=1,precision=5,dec sep align,column name={$y$}},
every first row/.append style={before row={%
    \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
    \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    $k$ &  $z$ & $\hat{x}_{k+1}$ & $P_{k+1}$ & $K_{k+1}$ \\ \toprule
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{5}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
    \toprule
    %
    $k$ & $z$ & $\hat{x}_{k+1}$ & $P_{k+1}$ & $K_{k+1}$ \\ \toprule
    \endhead
    %
    \midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endfoot
    %
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{5}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    }},%
    %
]{dataa.dat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one ampersand into definition:

```
    every first row/.append style={before row={%
        \caption{This is a Table with Data}%
        \label{tab:DataTable}\\\toprule
    &   $k$ &  $z$ & $\hat{x}_{k+1}$ & $P_{k+1}$ & $K_{k+1}$  %< -- on begging is added `&`
\\ \toprule
        \endfirsthead
        %
        \multicolumn{5}{c}%
        {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ Continued from previous page}} \\
        \toprule
        %
        $k$ & $z$ & $\hat{x}_{k+1}$ & $P_{k+1}$ & $K_{k+1}$ \\ \toprule
        \endhead
        %
        \midrule \multicolumn{5}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \bottomrule
        \endfoot
        %
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{5}{r}{{End of Table}} \\ \bottomrule
        \endlastfoot
        }},%
```

Why this necessary, I still don't know.

[image]

**Edit:**  Paul Gessler in his comment point me to funy thing: regardles, that the column number have all necessary ampersand, they are wrong placed. The cure to strange behavior is add ampersand before `k`.

Comment: I think the point of the question was that "k" should be above "1", "z" above "12", and so on. I don't understand why k and z are being merged like that.

Comment: probably, than the ampersand is missed between this two column names. I will correct this in my answer. Thank you to point this out.

Comment: That's what I don't understand, the ampersand is *not* missing... but still the columns are merged.

Comment: @PaulGessler, actually it is missing, but on the beginning pf row. Why, I do not know yet, I need to check manual and all code carefully again (but here is after midnight, i.e. time for sleep :-) .